# python : JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json

Learning from my past post on this ,i have pasted whole code .  Below is what i am doing :

in My code , i am creating and changing directory  and saving Json file in that directory , making sure i am not referencing  empty Json  or  a JSON file with the same file that could  giving me this error

```
time=datetime.now().strftime("%Y_%m_%d-%I_%M_%S_%p")
docfilename='network health check Report' +'-' + time
# Get the current working directory
current_dir = os.getcwd()

print("Saving file in directory-" + docfilename)
if not os.path.exists(docfilename):
    os.mkdir(docfilename)

# Define the path of the new directory
new_dir_path = os.path.join(current_dir, docfilename)

os.chdir(new_dir_path)
```

In my python script i am  running a PowerShell script  which generates couple of JSON files  and saves in the directory created above as shown below  :

```
    ps_script = 'H:\Eurrowings Health check\Azure-LBheathcheck.ps1'
    args = ["-AzureUsername", azure_username, "-pass", azure_password]
    process1 = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe", "-File", ps_script] + args)
    process1.wait()
    print("Exit code:", process1.returncode)
```

[image]

I run below then  and get error .

```
f = open('publicIpaddress-Aviatrix-firenet-nv-p-3z-inet-vnet-02.json')
  data = json.load(f)
```

Error:

[image]

Please help me on the same .. how to fix this .

I have made sure , i am in the right directory as it is not  giving me "file not  found error " .. I have also validated Json format is valid online ..
[image]

Edit1: adding  print(f.read()) output

```
     f = open('publicIpaddress-Aviatrix-firenet-nv-p-3z-inet-vnet-02.json')

   print(f.read())
```

[image]

Comment: I think the best way for you to debug this is to print the contents of the file in code - replace the json loading with `print(f.read())` and check that it has the expected content

Comment: Looks like you have a couple of unexpected characters at the beginning of the file?

Comment: hi @mihai: I have added screenshot of print(f.read()) to the   post .  it has the JSON content but what is strange to me is how it is looking in output . Given these file are generated from ConvertTo-Json  , is this something related to encoding or something ..? .. Also i do notice a  "ÿþ" sign at the start of output  in front of [  ..what does that mean  ?

Comment: @nick :  I am using  below powershell commands to generate JSON files : ..sample code below                                                                                                                                                   
[string]$jsonfilename ="publicIpaddress-" + "$lbname" +".json"
$finaldata1=$result |ConvertTo-Json
$finaldata1 | out-file $jsonfilename

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that your input file is encoded as UTF-16; the `ÿþ` at the beginning of the data is the byte-order-mark (BOM). You'll need to open the file in binary mode, read the contents and then decode them:

```py
f = open('publicIpaddress-Aviatrix-firenet-nv-p-3z-inet-vnet-02.json', 'rb')
content = f.read()
data = json.loads(content.decode('utf-16'))
```